# Long PHP script resulting in 500 error at 10-minute mark

Tags: php, wordpress, internal-server-error

I have max_execution_time set to 30 minutes, but this long-running loop is resulting in a 500-error at exactly the 10 minute mark each time.

1. How can I prevent that, what PHP setting is causing the 10-minute timeout?
2. Is there a better way to run this long loop? It's in a WordPress plugin activiation file, where it's grabbing up a large DB table of user-likes, which users liked which post, and assigning that meta to the post/activity itself.

---

```
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT activity_id FROM wp_wpsn_activity_likes GROUP BY activity_id" );
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    $act_id = $row->activity_id;
    $prep = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT user_id FROM wp_wpsn_activity_likes WHERE activity_id = %d", $act_id );
    $user_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $prep );
    
    bp_activity_update_meta( $act_id, 'wpsn_likes', serialize( $user_ids ) );   
}
```

Comment: It depends on what's causing the error. Have you checked your error logs to see what the actual error is? It could be an out of memory error, for example.

Comment: Nothing is being reported, it's exactly the 10 minute mark each time

Comment: It’s better to use batching and feed the data needed to be updated to a script that will not be running for that long. PHP is a script, therefore it’s not suited to running an indefinite loop, even though there are settings for it.

Comment: This is essentially a nested query. Start by reworking your query to `JOIN the two tables and retrieve the data you want. Let the database do the donkey work and off-load your PHP.

Comment: Just an idea but could it be your browser essentially giving up on the request since you're getting no errors?